# constructing string from NULL?

Tags: c++, string, c++17

After some change of the code-base I came accross this gotcha:

```
#include <string>

void test(const std::string& s){
}

int main()
{
    test(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7uJnef

This throws an exception. Changing to 'nullptr' helps nothing (still no error or warning).

I guess my question is, is there a way to detect or find this error at pre-runtime throughout the sourcecode ? perhaps some compiler warning, etc. (using MSVC VS-2017)

**I ended up modifying the basic_string template ala. `basic_string(int) = delete;
    basic_string(::std::nullptr_t) = delete;` - this won't catch all cases but does indeed seem to catch  the direct cases at least**

Comment: This is a job for a static analyzer.  `std::string` has a `cont char*` converting constructor so you can't stop it from accepting a null pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver exactly (Im painfully aware of that) - do you think cpp core check can help here ?

Comment: I would hope so.  They should be able to detect the null pointer dereference.

Comment: Accept nullptr or not is a pre-condition question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running [`cppcheck`](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) (version 1.89) on the example file yields:

> ```
> Checking test.cpp ...
> test.cpp:9:10: error: Null pointer dereference [nullPointer]
> test(NULL);
>      ^
> ```

Comment: I will try that

Comment: Last time I've checked cppcheck it suffered from lack of proper C++11 support and complained about syntax errors everywhere. Did they fix this and even implement support for C++17 in recent releases?

Comment: @VTT I think they try to be roughly up to date (no idea w.r.t C++17, but the C++11 basics should be fine), but I guess manually specifying which tests to run might be the way to go.

Comment: It seems VS2017 cpp core check is not able to detect this one

Comment: @lubgr I tried to give cppcheck a spin - what options are you using exactly ? at first it doesn't find this error - checking includes it tells me it cannot find <string> header but tells me this isn't an issue...

Comment: I ran it without any options, with a standard homebrew installation. Maybe you need to tell it where to look for standard headers? I guess the warning can only show up if `<string>` is found.

Comment: I ended up modifying the basic_string template ala. `    basic_string(int) = delete;
    basic_string(::std::nullptr_t) = delete;` - this ofc. won't catch all cases but does indeed seem to catch  the direct cases at least

Answer (score 3):

You can add a couple of prohibited overloads capturing use of `0`, `NULL` or `nullptr` arguments:

```
void test(int bad_argument) = delete;
void test(::std::nullptr_t bad_argument) = delete;
```

Comment: If we just could add this to std::string itself- then it would be great !

Comment: You need an overload for `void test(const char*)` as well (and have it call `test("")` if null), otherwise the caller can do something like `const char *s = nullptr; test(s);` and still crash at runtime.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thats a good point - I am less worried about that situation at the time being though

Comment: I ended up modifying the basic_string template ala. `    basic_string(int) = delete;
    basic_string(::std::nullptr_t) = delete;` - this ofc. won't catch all cases but does indeed seem to catch  the direct cases at least

Answer (score 2):

You can add a trampoline function that checks for NULL pointer at compile (and run) time, if your compiler supports it. For GCC it would look like this:

```cpp
void test(const std::string& s){

}

void test(const char* ptr  __attribute__((nonnull))) {
    test(std::string(ptr));
}

int main()
{
    test(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

The warning you get is:

```
<source>:13:14: warning: null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument [-Wnonnull]

    test(NULL);
         ~~~~^
```

Comment: Even without compile-time checking for null, you should still use a trampoline, it can do something like this to ensure no exception is thrown on a null pointer: `void test(const char* ptr) { if (!ptr) ptr = ""; test(std::string(ptr)); }` or `void test(const char* ptr) { test(std::string(ptr ? ptr : "")); }`